# Sort array of days in ascending order

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, sorting

I have an array that contains unique strings of day names. The day names will be in random order. - eg:

```
["Sun 10am", "Sat 4pm", "Sat 10am", "Wed 3pm", "Sun 4pm"]
```

I want to use javascript to sort that array so that it will be in ascending order.

```
["Wed 3pm", "Sat 10am", "Sat 4pm", "Sun 10am", "Sun 4pm"]
```

Can anybody suggest the best way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: It's easy. You just need to set priority value for each token for a day. Then you can sort this with a comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the combination of `map` and `sort`. Here I am converting time in 24 Hours format for easy comparison of numbers.

```js
var array = ["Sun 10am", "Sat 4pm", "Sat 10am", "Wed 3pm", "Sun 4pm"], 
mapping = { Mon: 1, Tue: 2, Wed: 3, Thu: 4, Fri: 5, Sat: 6, Sun: 7 },

result = array
  .map((time, i) => {
    const hour = parseInt(time.split(" ")[1], 10);
    const hour24 = time.indexOf("am") > -1 ? hour : hour + 12;
    return {
      index: i,
      day: mapping[time.split(" ")[0]],
      hour24
    }
  })
  .sort((a, b) => a.day - b.day || a.hour24 - b.hour24)
  .map(({
    index
  }) => array[index]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could take an object for the values of the day and sort by the time.

```js
const
    getTime = string => {
        var [day, hour, meridian] = string.match(/^(\D{3}) (\d+)(am|pm)/).slice(1),
            days = { Mon: 1, Tue: 2, Wed: 3, Thu: 4, Fri: 5, Sat: 6, Sun: 7 };

        return days[day] * 24 + +hour + (meridian === 'pm' && 12) + (hour === '12' && -12);
    };
var array = ["Sun 10am", "Sat 4pm", "Sat 10am", "Wed 3pm", "Sun 4pm", "Sat 12pm", "Sat 12am"];

array.sort((a, b) => getTime(a) - getTime(b));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: But "Sat 10am" should come before "Sat 4pm" right? @Nina Scholz

Comment: @DeepshikhaChaudhary, you are right. please see edit.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes its fine now.(I didn't downvted). Can I ask the reason for `(hour === '12' && -12)`.

Answer (score 4):

- You can create a object with days names as keys and values increasing from 1 to 7.
- Create a helper function which takes second part of string i.e `3pm,10am..` as input and add `12` to result if its `pm`
- Also divide the result by `24` so first `sort` should happen on days.
- Use the `sort()` function and for each value add the time index(which will be always less than 1) to the day index(`1,2,3...`) and subtract it for both value.

```js
const arr = ["Sun 10am", "Sat 4pm", "Sat 10am", "Wed 3pm", "Sun 4pm"];


function getTime(str){
  let time = str.slice(0,-2);
  let isAm = str.includes('am');
  return (isAm ? +time : +time + 12)/24
}

function sortTime(arr){
  let days = {
    Mon:1,
    Tue:2,
    Wed:3,
    Thur:4,
    Fri:5,
    Sat:6,
    Sun:7
  }
  return arr.slice().sort((a,b) => {
    let [day1,time1] = a.split(' ');
    let [day2,time2] = b.split(' ');
    return (days[day1] + getTime(time1)) - (days[day2] + getTime(time2)) 
  })
  
}

console.log(sortTime(arr))
```